# How select the min between a SQL value and a fixed number

Tags: sql, ms-access, min

I have to run this query in SQL that will return the min between a fixed scalar (let's say 7) and the value in the column. I tried:

```
SELECT from theTable min(theTable.Column , 7) AS Label
```

I get an error saying that I am using the wrong number of arguments in a function on this expression. I cannot copy/paste because I am using Access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  IIF(theTable.Column < 7, theTable.Column, 7) AS Label
FROM
  theTable
```